# Android preferences screen with interdependent values

Tags: android, android-preferences

My application has a preference screen where one value depends on the value of another preference.  For example, for two integer values A and B, A has to be more then B.  I could update the value of one to match the other.  So, if A = 10, B = 5, and the user set's B to 15, I can set A to 16, but that seems confusing to the user.  I can also not allow the user to set an invalid value, and try to explain which other value it depends on.  However, this might be confusing.

I was wondering if Android already has some established or preferred way of visualizing this for the user so that it is straightforward and easy.

Thank you,

Comment: Why not create your own `DialogPreference`? If the values are linked to each other I would expect to find them in one place...